# Momentum labels in feynmp package

Tags: labels, feynmp

I'm trying to draw a simple Feynman diagram and momentum labels aren't showing, I don't know why, even when I've checked everything and it seems okay. This is the piece of code where the problem is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}


\begin{document}


\begin{fmffile}{df10}
\begin{equation}
\tilde{G}^{(2)}(p,-p)=\quad \parbox{100pt}{
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,50) 
        \fmfleft{i1}
        \fmfright{o1}
        \fmf{scalar,label = $p$}{i1,o1}
        \fmfdot{i1,o1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}}
\quad + \frac{1}{2} \quad\parbox{100pt}{
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,80)
       \fmfleft{i1}
       \fmfright{o1}
       \fmftop{m}
       \fmfdot{i1,o1}
       \fmf{scalar,tension=1,label = $p$}{i1,v1}
       \fmf{scalar,tension=1,label = $-p$}{o1,v1}
       \fmf{scalar,right,tension=0,label = $k$,label.side=top}{v1,m,v1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}} \quad  + O(\lambda^2)
\end{equation}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code into a small example we can compile please, starting with your document class and ending with `\end{document}` preferably, just a small file that we can test on please

Comment: You're code doesn't compile, could you copy and paste the code in the question to a new file and then make the changes needed to make it compile please? Difficult to help if the code can't be run to test solutions etc

Comment: Sorry about the problems, but I don't understand why it isn't working. I've copied the code to a new Overleaf document and runned it without issues. Could it be some option in the Overleaf menu what is causing the problem? @JamesT

Comment: Indeed, I compiled it on Overleaf just now and it worked, must be my local installation of TeX, sorry for that

Comment: When you compiled it, did the momentum labels appeared?@JamesT

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring too but the image I included in your question is the output I got from Overleaf

Comment: When I compiled it, the labels aren't visible. I saw it now, sorry, I'm not used to this website, I'm new. You are getting the same as I, but in the code I have labels on in some \fmf commands. I don't understand why they aren't showing. I can't open a chat to talk because I'm new, so I have to talk throught comments, sorry. @JamesT

Comment: FIXED. For anyone wondering what the problem was, you must put the 'label' command inside \fmf without spaces between the word labeland the equal sign and the equal sign and the text of the label.

Comment: feel free to post a self-answer so people can vote on it, you can accept it to keep the site clean and help future readers who come across the issue :) well done on finding a solution, always a good feeling!